# Why showing other roles even not assigned while creating User in HANA Database?

Tags: hana

I am new to HANA Database. I am just trying to create new User in HANA DB through Eclipse systems editor. I have selected only below role as part of user creation.

**sap.hana.xs.lm.roles::Developer**

But, it is showing below roles as a result of executing query **select role_name from "PUBLIC"."EFFECTIVE_ROLES" where USER_NAME = 'TEST_USER';**

**ROLE_NAME**

**PUBLIC**

**sap.hana.xs.lm.roles::Developer**

**sap.hana.uis.db::SITE_USER**

**sap.hana.xs.lm.roles::Display**

**sap.hana.xs.lm.pe.roles::PE_Display**

Why being added other roles to user even not selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roles in SAP HANA are collections of **privileges** and **other roles**.
This can lead to a situation where a role contains several other roles, each of which can contain other roles and privileges. That way you have a hierarchy of direct and indirect role- and privileges assignments to a user account.

The system view you query is `EFFECTIVE_PRIVILEGES`. It’s single most important function is to *unroll* all roles that have been assigned directly **and** indirectly (effectively going through the roles-privileges-hierarchy) and to return all those assignments.
This “unrolling” of hierarchical structures is not easy/efficient to do in plain SQL, so this system view provides this special feature as a built-in functionality.

The pre-defined role `sap.hana.xs.lm.roles::Developer` contains several other roles (as your query result shows).
To double-check you can even review the role definition in the HANA XS repository by navigating to the`sap.hana.xs.lm.roles` package, as this role is delivered as a *design-time* artefact.

If you actually only want to see the **direct** assignments of roles/privileges to a user (or to roles), using system views `GRANTED_ROLES` or `GRANTED_PRIVILEGES` will get you that.